# Mail.app doesn't delete the draft email after I have sent it

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I use Mail.app to access my Gmail account and it doesn't delete the draft email - which is created automatically - after I have sent it. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See point #18 on [this TidBITS article on making Mail.app and Gmail IMAP co-exist happily](http://db.tidbits.com/article/10253) -- hopefully it will help?

(I have not yet taken all the recommendations they give, but the longer I go on using both, the more I turn back to this to help file off the rough edges.)